# Using emails to input database

Tags: mysql, email

I am wondering how to use emails as a database input.

I would like to be able to create unique emails to enter content in a mysql database.
Just as tumblr's "mail to post" feature that creates a unique email for each user. When you send an email to this address, your subject becomes title and your body the content.

I would  need a very simple DB : email (expeditor), subject, content 
And to create as much tables as i create emails.

Is it clear enough?

I cannot figure out how to get the emails of a specific email address and insert their content in a database.

The idea behind this is to use an arduino to read the database and print new entries via a thermal printer.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:arduino]?

Comment: Basically nothing !
I am just explaining the whole project so you can have a more accurate overview :)
But my question really is on the email thing.
Thank you for your interest

Comment: There are many ways that one can accomplish this feat.  Broadly speaking, either you must run an application which polls a mailbox (e.g. over POP3 or IMAP) or the MDA (which receives the email over SMTP) can push the email into the database.  The solution that is right for you will depend on many factors, including the amount of control you have over the email infrastructure.

Comment: What do you mean by "the amount of control" ?

Comment: Can you configure the DNS so that mail is delivered to an MDA that is under your control?  Can you configure the MDA and/or run software of your choosing on the same machine?  Things like that.

Comment: Ok, seems rather heavy. Isn't there an easy way to achieve this ? I am building it as a proof of concept, so shouldn't be too complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.

(a) You can use a script or service that the mail server calls whenever a database entry email arrives. That script or service will update the database.

(b) You can use a rule in the email client to call an application or script whenever the appropriate email arrives. That application or script will update the database.

(c) You can write an application that checks an email account for the appropriate emails, then updates the database.

Comment: Option a seems the clearer.
Found this nice explanation : http://badjava.com/node/37